# REST API - JSON format consistency

Tags: json, rest, api-design

I've been searching the web for this and haven't found an answer to a quite simple question: should JSON formats be the same for all HTTP verbs for a specific resource?

For example:

`GET http://example.com/api/articles` returns

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    ref: "21313-453542"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    ref: "23424-234243"
  }, ...
]
```

`GET http://example.com/api/articles/2` returns

```
{
  id: 2,
  ref: "23424-234243",
  name: "Cofee",
  price: 23,
  provider: "112-411",
}
```

Is this a good practice or JSON objects should always keep a consistent format? To make myself clear, if the formats should be consistent the first request should return something like this:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    ref: "21313-453542",
    name: "Oranges",
    price: 34,
    provider: "2424-12",
  }
  {
    id: 2,
    ref: "23424-234243",
    name: "Cofee",
    price: 23,
    provider: "112-411",
  }
]
```

Comment: for best practice just create mapping object and return it

Comment: What "json format" do you mean exactly? The extra properties, or wrapping it in an array?

Comment: I mean each of the elements inside the array compared to the single element. I edited the question to make it clear :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, you should use the same "schema" for the JSON data returned from the endpoints you give as example, since I would expect that the `http://example.com/api/articles/2` API call can be used to obtain a single *article* whereas the  `http://example.com/api/articles` can be used to obtain all the available *articles*, but the *article* data representation is the same.

If you want to provide a "compact" representation of the article entities, for example using only the `id` and `ref` attributes as in your first JSON representation, you should provide a different API endpoint, for example:

`http://example.com/api/articles-refs` or `http://example.com/api/articles/refs`

You should adopt this representation strategy for any suitable HTTP verb (for example GET, POST, PUT), while verbs such as DELETE normally requires only the *id* of the entity to delete, since the additional entity attributes are useless for the specific API operation.

This leads to a consistent and easy to use API, IMHO.

Anyhow, you should always **document** your API to provide information to the API consumers about the available operations, their semantic and the JSON schema of the input/output data.

You can use Swagger/OpenAPI for API documentation. If you use Java to implement your API, I've published ar [article on DZone](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-jersey-and-swagger-always-happy-togeth) about this.

Comment: Thanks, great answer!

Answer (score 0):

There are usually at least two 'views' of the same data - a summary that includes limited information that is used for returning in lists, and a detailed view that contains all the information for queries that just return the one entity. The problem with returning very detailed information in lists is that it usually involves more complex, less performant queries to the database.

So it's a good idea to split your views in this way.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendations:

1. The formats should be consistent. It make documentation much easier.
2. Replace everywhere **id** field with **uri** field. It is better if the client always sees URIs instead of ids.

For example:

```
{
  uri: "http://example.com/api/articles/2",
  ref: "23424-234243",
  name: "Cofee",
  price: 23,
  provider: "112-411",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a object pattern(generally a map) for each type of resource you have.

/api/resources (GET) - Should list all the resources

/api/resources/$resource_id (GET) - Should return a particular resource

/api/resources(POST) - Should create and return the newly created resource

/api/resources/$resource_id (PUT) - Should return the particular edited resource

/api/resources/$resource_id (DELETE) - Set HTTP 204 response code (No-Content)

Only the list resources api should give a list of objects. All the other API types can return just the object map.

*Band-width optimisation :* 
If you want to restrict the data sent to client, you can support a query parameter **fields**. If this field is not given, you can return the whole object representation of your resource.
/api/resources?fields=id,ref